# Page with automatic scrolling bug when I click on a checkbox or when I make any changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This happens when I make any changes to the screen, it always moves the page to the calendar, I have no idea what may have caused it, if anyone knows a common cause that may have caused it, I appreciate it.

follow the link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwf7y.gif

Comment: Really hard to understand what is happening from a gif. Try to give us a codesandbox or some snippets to actually see the problem